# Why isn't a conceptual Git article out there without any piece of console juggling?

Tags: git, documentation

I have googled this about 10 times or more, but couldn't find any fine explanation of things like rebase, stash, reflow, submodules (!), reflog etc.

I'd like drawings, figures, metaphors, only the concepts. And I bet many developers would like it as I'd do. Actual command line tools / GUIs can be one's personal preference after.

Do you know such a piece of article / post / PDF / video / whatever?

Comment: Yap, I knew it is a closee question... ..I'm still seeking, though.

Comment: stackoverflow, where the useful questions are closed as off-topic, and the useless answers are showered with upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The famous ["Git Parable"](http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html) is pretty metaphoric and contains precisely zero console juggling.

On a more serious note, I reckon most guides show Git console commands simply to *demonstrate* the concepts being discussed; so take any guide and ignore the commands.

Having said that, I find the following guides to be of very high quality while mostly focusing on concepts rather than commands:

- ["Git concepts simplified"](http://gitolite.com/gcs.html) (by the way, written by the author of `gitolite`).
- ["Git for computer scientists"](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/).
- ["Git from the bottom up"](http://newartisans.com/2008/04/git-from-the-bottom-up/).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of visual resources out there:

1. Did you not find the pictures in the most recommended Git book, [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html), to be helpful?
2. [Learn Git Branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) is a free one that can help you understand rebase.
3. [Atlassian has some Git guides](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history) with pictures.
4. [Code School has Git video courses](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/git-real) that can explain Git concepts with pictures, though it is not free.